# Random copy of List<T>

Tags: c#, list, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient way to randomly “sort” (Shuffle) a list of integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c)

How to effectively create a random copy of `List<T>`?

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("A");
myList.Add("B");
myList.Add("C");

// Now an extension method or a function which returns a random arrangement of myList:

List<string> GetRandomList()
{
    // List<string> result = new List<string>();
    // Random rnd = new Random();
    // Inside a loop
    // result.Add(myList[rnd.Next(1, myList.Count)]);
}
```

The extension method woud be `public static List<T> Shuffle(List<T> this)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459264/why-is-fisher-yates-the-most-useful-shuffling-algorithm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343797/is-this-c-implementation-of-fisher-yates-shuffle-correct

Comment: @Mitch: I didn't know the right term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a Shuffle, there are various implementations out there, usually the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle).

Below a generic implementation taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c/1262619#1262619):

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Note that this re-orders the list *in place*, it's easy enough to refactor it to return a new list if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Down side is it changes the list itself instead of returning a new shuffled list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<T> Random<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    return collection.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
}
```

Thanks to [Jeff Atwood for this solution](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html).

Comment: Will that only call the delegate once per item in the collection, or multiple times? Let's say we wanted to shuffle the list `{1, 2, 3}`, and the OrderBy implementation decided to compare `1` vs. `2`, and then `1` vs `3`. It would call the delegate, which would call `NewGuid`, but when it wanted to compare `1` against two different numbers, would it call `NewGuid` only once, or multiple times? If it calls multiple times, then this does not produce a good shuffle, and the final order depends greatly on the implementation of OrderBy.

Comment: It will call it multiple times.

Comment: See http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html for an interesting analysis of the results of doing shuffles in a bad way. In that case, the comparison function (`int Compare(object a, object b)`) returned a random number 1 or -1. Because of the way the sort was implemented, the resulting ordering was not random, and it varied by sort implementation.